# Fetching Name for same Birthday From NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I have an array of dictionaries which is having Birthday and Name as keys. I want to retrieve value for name having same birthdays.

```
    for (NSDictionary *contactDict in contactList) {
            NSString *birthdayStr = [contactDict objectForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY];
}
```

What should I do to get an array of name for same birthdays.

Comment: What do you mean by same birthdays? Like, when you have a birthday string, get all the names corresponding to it? Or get a list of all names that have a birthday that is a duplicated somewhere?

Comment: Suppose that Dict has value as 1/12/13,A ;1/12/13,B ; 2/12/13,C. Then I need an array for 1/12/13 and 2/12/13 as (A,B) and C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for (NSDictionary *contactDict in contactList) {
    NSString *birthdayStr = [contactDict objectForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY];

    // indexes of all array objects with same birthday:
    NSIndexSet *matching = [contactList indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *contactDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [[contactDict objectForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY] isEqualToString:birthdayStr];
    }];

    NSArray *matchingNames = [[contactList objectsAtIndexes:matching] valueForKey:NAME_KEY];
    NSLog(@"%@", matchingNames);
}
```

Or, if you want only one name array for each distinct birthday:

```
// Set of all distinct birthdays:
NSSet *allBirthdays = [NSSet setWithArray:[contactList valueForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY]];

for (NSString *birthdayStr in allBirthdays) {
    NSLog(@"birthday: %@", birthdayStr);

    NSIndexSet *matching = [contactList indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *contactDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [[contactDict objectForKey:BIRTHDAY_KEY] isEqualToString:birthdayStr];
    }];

    NSArray *matchingNames = [[contactList objectsAtIndexes:matching] valueForKey:NAME_KEY];
    NSLog(@"names: %@", matchingNames);
}
```

*Output for your sample data:*

```
birthday: 1/12/13
names: (
    A,
    B
)
birthday: 2/12/13
names: (
    C
)
```

Comment: Thnx martin.This was exactly I was looking for...Thanks a lot